Could not Fast Refresh (Component is incompatible)
I have a useSwitchHotel query to mutate some data. The useSwitchHotel must be rendered when there is some change in state in dashboard page. But the mutate query doesn't even run when the state changes. What might cause this issue ?
I am expecting for someone to guide me as I am new to software development.

Please provide the relevant code for assistance

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
